# Best options for automated deployments in a primarily C based environment

Tags: c, build, automation

I am working in a Real Time SCADA environment that is primarily C and Pascal based(some KSH and C++ as well). The servers all are running AIX(about 70 servers) . Currently we manually deploy every change. What are some options for automated deployment? We also have Java 1.5 installed in our environment.

Comment: Deployment of what? Changes in what?

Comment: C executable(s), config file changes etc.

Comment: Executables are not C, they are binary. This is not related to C unless you are interested in compiling the executable on each target machine. Which doesn't make much sense if these have the same architecture and OS.

Comment: I understand that. I am really looking for a good way to push out the executable, make config changes and bring up and down the application on each machine easily.. Something like Jenkins

Comment: Can you make SSH connections to the servers?  If you can, I'd set up an update account (same specs on each; same uid and gid on all servers), so that some central machines can SSH to that account on each using keys only, then automate the updates using shell scripts that "push" the changes. Use one virtual machine for testing; virtual machine so that you can revert the pushed changes, and retry until it works without issues. Always test pushes on the virtual machine first.

Comment: If you are familiar with and like Jenkins, why don't you use it?

Comment: Jenkins have continuous integration for C/C++. Check out https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/07/jenkins-conan/

Comment: @TonyB The current release of Jenkins is not compatible with the old version of java we have. The environment I work in is a safety critical environment (scada control for large power lines) so we can't install new software easily.